# How to link parse customer to Stripe customer

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe and Parse cloud service to charge a card. Charging is all fine, but I don't know which user made the purchase.  My application requires user to log in via Parse user to make the purchase.

I want to know
1. how can I create a Stripe customer using parse cloud code (JS). 
2. how can I link that Stripe customer to the customer currently logged into my application (e.g [PFUser currentUser] from parse).

right now I have a vc to add credit card

```
[[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:stripeCard
                                      completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {
                                              [self handleStripeError:error];
                                          } else {
                                              NSString *myVal = token.tokenId;
                                              NSLog(@"%@",token.tokenId);
                                              [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"createBackendChargeWithToken" withParameters:@{@"token":myVal}
                                                                          block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                                                              if (!error) {
                                                                                  NSLog(@"Success: from Cloud Code Res: %@",result);
                                                                                  self.pay.enabled = YES;
                                                                              }
                                                                              else
                                                                              {
                                                                                  NSLog(@"Error: from Cloud Code: %@",error);
                                                                                  self.pay.enabled = YES;
                                                                              }

                                                                          }];
                                                                        }
                                      }];
```

and my main.js is as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createBackendChargeWithToken", function(request, response){
var stripeToken = request.params.token;
    var charge = Stripe.Charges.create({
    amount:1000,
    currency:"usd",
    card: stripeToken,
},{
    success: function(httpResponse){
    response.success("Purchase made!");
    },
    error: function(httpResponse){
    response.error("no good");
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, initialize the Stripe module in your cloud code:

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
var STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = '[your secret key]';
var STRIPE_API_BASE_URL = 'api.stripe.com/v1'; //this is used for making http requests for parts of the Stripe API that aren't covered in parse's stripe module
Stripe.initialize( STRIPE_SECRET_KEY );
```

I create a card token on the client side, and pass that into my cloud code function so I'm never sending sensitive data. The cloud code function is pretty simple:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("StripeRegisterUser", function(request, response)
{   
    Stripe.Customers.create({
        card: request.params.stripeToken // the token id should be sent from the client
        },{
            success: function(customer) {
                console.log(customer.id);
                response.success(customer.id); 
            },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
                console.log(httpResponse);
                response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"+httpResponse);
            }
        });
});
```

I'm actually storing the customer.id, which I'm passing as my response back to my client, to the user object, but that's on my client side code. You could add that code into this cloud function. `request.user` would be the user who called this cloud code function.

The Stripe module doesn't have the complete Stripe API, so I use that base URL to create custom http requests based off of the curl examples in Stripe's API docs.

Getting the user's card data requires an httpRequest, as the Stripe API doesn't include a method for that:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("StripeUserCards", function(request, response)
{   
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method:"GET",

        url: "https://" + STRIPE_SECRET_KEY + ':@' + STRIPE_API_BASE_URL + "/customers/" + request.params.customer_id + "/cards",

        success: function(cards) {
            response.success(cards["data"]);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
});
```

You'll have to figure out how to parse the returned data yourself. It's of type "id" in obj-c.

The Stripe.Charges.create method in Parse requires both a customer id and a card id. Use that user card info on the client side to allow a user to select which card they want to use, send the card id to a method that creates a charge, and pass in that card id along with the customer id attached to the user object.

I paid a guy a lot of money to help me with this stuff, so I'm not gonna be able to give you more specific help.

Comment: That's pretty much what I have.  I generate a token from my app and pass it in cloud functions but I went straight to pay, and now I want to added it to a user. I have two follow up questions then. First, Stripe.Customers.create always create a new customer, but what if the [PFUser currentUser] was already created.   Second, maybe I missed something, but how is creating a customer in Stripe linked to the logged in user in Parse?  My last resort is to store last four digits, exp month/year on parse as they are not sensitive according to PCI.

Comment: Creating a user returns a customer id that you store on your Parse user. In the Charges.create method, you pass in that customer id along with the card id that they used. Since you have a stored user, you can pull all of the user's card objects, and allow them to choose which of their added cards they want to use, and you pass both the customer id and associated card id into the charge method.

Comment: So I would create a field called StripID or something on my parse user?  Can you give me some sample code on how I can store credit on a parse user and how I can retrieve the credit card information to pass it in to Charges.create?  Really appreciate it.  I will update my code in the question for you to see.

Comment: Updated my answer, but that's as much as I'll be able to help you.